# call functions from separate files with Meteor

Tags: function, meteor, file-structure

I want to create an application in Meteor,
from what I understand the manual it first loads which are in
subdirectories, and then follows the alphabetical order.
My file structure is like this ...

```
/server
/lib
/client
    /lib
        game.js -> already starts declaring the function "makeBoard(){}"
    /template.js -> where the function "makeBoard()" is called.
```

thus appears that the error function "makeBoard()" does not exist, only works if I declare in the same file where I want to call it. Even when I move the file "game.js" to the same directory where "template.js", it happens.
How should I correctly make references to resources that are in different files on Meteor?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Define the function with `makeBoard = function() { ... }`.

Functions defined with `function foo() { ... }` are local to the file, as are variables defined with `var bar = ...`.

Comment: With the EMCA6 release, and specifically the `"use strict"` tag for javascript code this solution doesn't compile. I strongly suggest @Shwaydogg solution for that reason.

Comment: This works CLIENT SIDE only. Please see Shwaydogg's answer for a SERVER side fix using Meteor.MyFunction.Method()

Answer (score 52):

Using a globally defined variable, as avital suggests, will work, but is not a recommended code design choice ([see JS mistake 1 listed here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-10-javascript-mistakes-youre-making/)).

Instead in your `lib` directory you could create a file with:

```
Meteor.myFunctions = {
...
    makeBoard : function() { ... },
...
}
```

Then in any other js file you could call `Meteor.myFunctions.makeBoard()`.  This should be done in the `lib` directory because Meteor guarantees the js files in `lib` are loaded before other directories, so your function will already be loaded.

Comment: Very clever. If you are sharing functions from multiple files this will make it possible:
Meteor['myFunctions'] = Meteor['myFunctions'] || {};

Meteor['myFunctions']['createinstanceclass'] = function () {
    return new instanceclass();
}
Meteor['myFunctions'] = Meteor['myFunctions'] || {};
Meteor['myFunctions']['createsolutionclass'] = function () {

    return new solutionClass();

}
If you agree please add it to your answer; if not please explain how to do it better :)

Comment: THANK YOU. Finally got some custom server side codes running. I tried running this on the client, and it DID NOT work, as expected. Fantastic.